# JQuery, Hierarchical Table pagination

Tags: jquery, html, pagination, hierarchical-trees

Hierarchical Table and table pagination is asked several times. But I am looking for both of them together. Am already using JQuery in my application so plugin using same will be useful, but I am open for any suggestion. At present I managed to display Hierarchical data by using some jQuery plugin and added my own pagination method, but it is falling short.

I am looking for something like this with pagination.
http://docvert.org/holloway.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/treeview1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you give [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) a try?

Update due to comment: navigate to http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html, on the left click **advanced** and then **grid as subgrid**.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: I have checked jqGrid earlier and found it does not support Hierarchical data. If I have missed it provide me with link for same.

Comment: Finally I settled on backend solution as Data just got bigger (20000+ rows). jqGrid comes close to what I had in mind. Could implement jqGrid sooner due to effort required in making it suitable for current website theme.