# It's possible to create ajax table with pagination in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that loads data to the table using ajax. This table should have pagination and sorting, use custom CSS stylesheet and provide custom layout. At last one I don't want to use jTable, because it doesn't provide custom layout.

Comment: Any code that you have tried? Have you tried search engine on SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065137/jquery-hierarchical-table-pagination?rq=1

Comment: http://bit.ly/1DD4aBO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First result on Google:

http://www.datatables.net/

> DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. It is a
>   highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive
>   enhancement, and will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML
>   table.

Please try searching for your answer first.

Comment: This solution really defeats the purpose of using ajax and paging. Why? Because it requires you to download the entire dataset.  If you have very large datasets it becomes unwieldy, which is why you want to use ajax and paging in the first place. So, I give it a thumbs down for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (i know bad idea) your returned data is json and you are building the table with jquery you could use [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to cut out the data you need and only render that, and then store the sliced data in an array so you can access them like pages on with yourjs powered pagination